# Reading value from one XML to another

Tags: java, sql, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have two XMLs (Queries.xml and EnvVar.xml) the first xml contains all my SQL queries my second xml contains the paramerters/environment variables etc.,

In Queries.xml each query is inside a tag, now for the WHERE clause in queries I want to read the conditions from EnvVar.xml, for example Select * from table WHERE Year in (2014,2015)... (2014,2015) comes from EnvVar.xml

Queries.xml as below:

```
<Queries> <Sql1> Select * from table Where Year in() </Sql1> </Queries>
```

EnvVar.xml as below:

```
<Parameters><Year>2014,2015</Year></Parameters>
```

With the below Java code I am able to read whats inside Sql1 is there a way to send year value from EnvVar to Queries?

```
public static String ReportQuery(String TagValue){
    String HTMLGlobalParameters=null;
    try {           
        URL url = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Queries.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(url.getPath());
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Queries");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                HTMLGlobalParameters = getTagValue(TagValue, eElement);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return HTMLGlobalParameters;

}
```

Comment: Based on what codition? What output do you expect to create?

Comment: As far as i understood you create the sql queries in xml file. Instead of parsing it why dont you use StringTokenizer ?

Comment: @MaciejLos: As I mentioned I am able to read what is inside Sql1 tag using above java code, I wish my final output as : Select * from table where year in (2014,2015)

Comment: The question about "based on what condition?" is still active. I do not see any relationship between sql query and its parameters...

Comment: @MaciejLos: If you are referring to condition for "sending of Year value from EnvVar to Queries"... then its without any conditions, Year for me is a parameter to be used in other queries as well, please let me know if I answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change `Queries.xml` to:

```
<Queries> <Sql1> Select * from table Where Year in(@Year@) </Sql1> </Queries>
```

Then when you have in `EnvVar.xml`:

```
<Parameters><Year>2014,2015</Year></Parameters>
```

Your tag is `Year` so try to find `'@'+Tag.Name+'@'` or `'@Year@'` in `Queries.xml` tag-value -or your query string- and replace it to `EnvVar.xml` tag-value -here if `2014,2015`-.

---

Your `ReportQuery` method with a little change can be a new method for getting a tag-value of `EnvVar.xml` file with a name like `ReportWhereClues`.

Now before `return HTMLGlobalParameters;` line in `ReportQuery` you can check `HTMLGlobalParameters` that there is any part of it like `@...@`, and by using 
`ReportWhereClues` with an argument that is the string between those `@` you can get the tag-value like `2014,2015`, Now replace `@...@` to that tag-value.

Comment: Sorry am new to java/xml, the function i mentioned "ReportQuery" reads whats inside Sql1 tag in Queries.xml please let know what changes you are suggesting.

Comment: @Vinod I can't give you the code right now, But I suggest you to try to understand the solution and try to code it yourself. I will add the code at next time, I must go! ;).